# My php code won't show back result form phpmyadmin (sql) database

Tags: php, sql, raspberry-pi, mariadb

So i recently set up a local web server on Raspberry Pi and I am currently experiencing little bit of trouble. I wrote a code (for test reasons) that after you click on one button in .html it runs test.php document that creates a table in sql, fills in the data and than prints the output.

```
<?php
$conn= mysqli_connect('localhost','admin','admin','database_test');
$createTable='CREATE TABLE Bank_statements(
id INT(3) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);';
$addData='INSERT INTO Bank_statements(firstName,lastName) VALUES ("peter","zupanc");';
$query='SELECT * FROM Bank_statements;';
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (mysqli_query($conn,$createTable)){
            echo 'sucess creating a table';
            if (mysqli_query($conn,$addData)){
                    echo 'sucess adding data <br>';
                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo $row['id'].$row['firstName'].$row['lastName']."<br>";
                    }
            }else{
                    echo 'error adding data<br>'.mysqli_error($conn);
            }
    }else{
            echo 'failed at creating table:<br>'.mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Everything goes as planed till part when php should return/echo $row but it doesn't its just empty space.

Comment: what does `var_dump($row)` give when put into the while loop?

Comment: same result...unfortunately nothing :/

Comment: Nothing or like NULL or an empty value? Because if it is nothing then the loop is not actually run at all. Go ahead and add debug outputs before the loop, e.g. see what `$result` really contains (which is false if the query failed)

Comment: first i echo-ed out $result and same thing happened (nothing even not NULL) but then i tried var_dump($result) and it appeared "bool(false)" so i guess my query didn't actually execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you executed `$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);` before the table was created in the DB.
The query is executed  when you call it. The `mysqli_fetch_array` just "transforms" a previous result row to an array format.

Try executing `mysqli_query($conn,$query)` right before the `while`.

I suggest also you define value for the `mysqli_fetch_array` second argument `$resulttype` (optional).

See docs for reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Default value (`MYSQLI_BOTH`) is usually an overkill and apparently you just want the result format that comes from using `MYSQLI_ASSOC`.